# I received an email from a trusted source which contains flags and symbols

Tags: symbols, flags

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #37: Rare and Endangered 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6389)</sup>

---

I received a strange message the other day via email, and I can't seem to make any sense out of it. The entire message is composed solely of flags and rockets.

> ️️️️ ️ ️️️ ️️️    ️️️️ ️ ️️ ️  ️ ️   ️ ️️   ️  ️ ️ 
>   ️️  ️   ️ ️️ ️ ️️ ️ ️   ️️ ️️ ️️ ️ ️️ ️   ️️️  ️ ️️ ️ ️ ️️ ️️ ️ 
>   ️️  ️   ️️ ️  ️️ ️ ️️️ ️️ ️ ️️ ️  ️  ️ ️ ️ ️️   ️️️  ️  ️️ ️️  ️️️️ ️ ️️️ ️️ 
>  
>   ️️ ️ ️️ ️ ️  ️️️ ️   ️  ️️ ️ ️️ ️️️ ️  ️ ️️ ️️️ ️️️ ️ ️️   ️️️️ ️  ️ ️️ ️ ️  ️ ️️️️   ️ ️ ️️️   ️  ️️️ ️  ️️️️ ️ ️️ 
>  
>   ️  ️     ️️ ️️   ️ ️️    ️  ️️  ️️ ️  ️️ ️  ️️   ️️ ️️️    ️️ ️ ️ ️️️ ️️️ ️ ️️  ️ ️️️ ️️️   ️️️️ ️    ️ ️ ️  ️️ ️   ️  ️️  ️️ ️  ️️ ️  ️️ ️  ️  ️️ ️️   ️ ️️  ️ ️️  ️ ️️ ️️  ️️ ️      ️️ ️️ ️ ️️️ ️ ️    ️  ️️ ️ ️️ ️️️ ️  ️️️ ️️    ️️ ️️️ ️️ ️ ️   ️️️️ ️    ️ ️ ️  ️️️  ️️  ️️  ️️️ ️️  ️️ ️️ ️ ️️️  ️ ️ ️️ ️ ️️️ 
>  
>   ️️ ️️️ ️ ️ ️️️ ️ ️️  ️️  ️ ️ ️ ️️       ️  ️ ️ ️️️  ️ ️️ ️  ️️ ️ ️️  ️  ️ ️️ ️️  ️️ ️   ️️️  ️️  ️  ️️️  ️ ️️️ ️️️  ️️️ ️ ️   ️️️  ️️ ️ ️️️️  ️️ ️️️ ️️  ️️️    ️️️️ ️   ️ ️   ️ ️   ️️ ️ ️ ️️️ ️️️ ️ ️️   ️️ ️️    ️ ️ ️     ️  ️️  ️  ️️  ️ ️️ ️️️ ️️️  ️️️ ️  ️️   ️️ ️ ️ ️️️ ️  ️ ️️  ️️ ️️     ️️️️️   ️️ ️️️ ️️️ ️️  ️  ️️ ️️️ ️️  ️️️  ️️  ️  ️️ ️️  ️️  ️  ️️ ️️ ️️️ ️️  ️️  ️ ️️️  
>   ️ ️️️ ️️️   ️️ ️️️ ️ ️ ️️️ ️  ️️️   ️  ️️️  ️️   ️  ️ ️ ️️    ️ ️️️ ️️️ ️ ️ ️ 
>  
>      ️ ️ ️️️ ️️ ️️ ️  ️️  ️️ ️️ ️ ️️   ️️  ️️ ️️ ️ ️️️ ️️  ️ ️️ ️ ️ ️️ ️   ️  ️ ️ ️️    ️ ️️️ ️️️ ️ ️ ️  ️ ️️ ️️️ ️️️  ️️️ ️  ️ ️ ️️  ️️ ️ ️️ 
>  
>    ️️️️ ️  ️️ ️️️️ ️️ ️ ️️️ ️  ️️ ️️️ 
>  
>   ️  ️️️ ️ ️️  ️ ️  ️ ️️  ️   ️ ️ ️️ ️ ️️️ ️
>   Samuel Joseph Alfred

Can you help me read it?

Comment: I want to say it is a version of morse code, but...

Comment: Flags may represent binary.

Comment: What font should I be using to see the flags?

Comment: I tred converting to binary and morse code with white flags (0 or -), black flags (1 or .) and vice-versa and rockets (spaces) , but with no success...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Really? You had no success with either of those?

Comment: Is that supposed to mean one of them should work?

Comment: I was doing one thing wrong, I'm getting somewhere now...

Comment: Can someone post a screenshot? I see square boxes mostly, and the rocket icon. No flags.

Comment: @BruceWayne Using [@GustavoGabriel's substitutions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/68076/24755), I've converted it to [a representative plaintext format](https://pastebin.com/raw/EwNj8HdD) for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The text are a kind of morse code where: 
>
>  White flags are dots, black flags are dashes and the rockets are spaces

The translated text:

> HELLO THERE JEO YUO KONW I AM ADEDAYO PRINCE OF NIGERIA I AM IN DESPERATE NEED OF YOUR HELP RECENTLY MY UNCLE KILLED THE KING WHO WAS MY FATHER NOW TO PROTECT MY COUNTRY I MUST TRANSFER ALL THE MONEY IN MY COUNTRY IN A PROTECTED ACCOUNT TO PREVENT MY UNCLE FROM USING THE MONEY FOR POLITICAL GAINS PLEASE, CONNECT TO MY WESTERN UNION ACCOUNT FOR A SMALL FEE OF 214 USD SO THAT WE MAY TRANSFER OUR MONEY TO YOU YOU WILL BE COMPENSATED UP TO 5 MILLION USD FOR YOUR CONTRIBUTIONS ALSO PLEASE LOOK FOR MY NEXT MESSAGE TO ENSURE CORRECT CORRESPONDENCE MY NEXT MESSAGE WILL BE ENCODED THE PHRASE IS A LAD NAMED E MANDALA

"Samuel Joseph Alfred":

> The names of the guys who developed the [morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code): Samuel F. B. Morse, the American physicist Joseph Henry, and Alfred Vail

Just curiosity:

I don't know how you guys normally do it, but this is how I translated from flags to morse code, since I'm a ruby developer (Not the best code, but it did the job :) ):

> `morse = "     ... "
>  parsed = ""
>  morse.each_char do |cur|
>   if cur == ""
>     parsed = parsed + "."
>   elsif cur == ""
>    parsed = parsed + "-"
>   elsif cur == ""
>     parsed = parsed + "/"
>   elsif cur == " "
>     parsed = parsed + " "
>   end
>  end`

Comment: Nice. So there should be a second and possibly third cipher. apparently the last phrase about A LAD NAMED E MANDALA is a palindrome. There is also the mangling of Joe's name to consider...