# That is a battlefield

Tags: cipher, knowledge

These [emails](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68129/a-lad-named-e-mandala) [keep](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68071/i-received-an-email-from-a-trusted-source-which-contains-flags-and-symbols?noredirect=1&lq=1) coming, and I can't block them. Apparently my ISP has told me that they're too secure to end up on my block list, and for some reason, I can't send these messages to spam. Whoever Adedayo is, he is insistent on getting his $214 USD. Coincedentally enough, when you change the numbers to letters, they spell the word "bad", I wonder if that means anything. Anyway, I digress, here is another encrypted message that this so called prince sent me.

> That is a battlefield
> On the starboard,
> At the port,
> We will clash,
> Until we decease
>
> 214
> Konami Code - Mirror's edge
>
> ɐqʍb ɥqɯ ʎʇɯ ıɯןʌ ƨɟƃd ʌƃɾɾ pq ʞʎ ɔƃןʍɾ ʍƨƨqʞυƨ ʍƨ ɹɯןƨʍɹƨƃןǝ ʎɯʇ ʍǝʍƃן ƃ ʍʞ ʍɐqɐʍʎɯ υbƃןɹq ɯɔ ןƃǝqbƃʍ ɟqƃb ƨɯ υɯʌqbd ɯɔ ƨɟq ǝɯɾɐ qʍǝɾq ƃ ןqqɐ ʎɯʇb ʍddƃdƨʍןɹq ƃן ɐqƨɟbɯןƃןǝ ʞʎ ʇןɹɾq ƨɟq ɹʇbbqןƨ ıƃןǝ ɟq ɟʍd dqƃzqɐ ƨɟq ʞɯןqʎ ƨɟʍƨ ƃ ɐqdυqbʍƨqɾʎ ƨbƃqɐ ƨɯ υbqnqןƨ ɟƃʞ ɔbɯʞ ƨʍıƃןǝ ʞʎ υqɯυɾq ɟʍnq ןqʍbɾʎ ɾɯdƨ ʍɾɾ ɟɯυq ʍɾɾ ɯƨɟqbd ƃ ɟʍnq bqʍɹɟqɐ ɯʇƨ ƨɯ ɟʍnq ƃǝןɯbqɐ ʞʎ υɾqʍ ʎɯʇ ʍbq ʞʎ ɯןɾʎ ɟɯυqυɾqʍdq pɯɯı ʍ ɔɾƃǝɟƨ ƨɯ ןƃǝqbƃʍ ʍd dɯɯן ʍd υɯddƃpɾq ɹɾʍƃʞ ƨɟʍƨ ʎɯʇ ʍbq ʍ ƨɯʇbƃdƨ ʞqqƨ ʞq ʍƨ ƨɟq ɯdʇןɯdɯǝpɯ dʍɹbqɐ ǝbɯnq ƨɯǝqƨɟqb ʌq ʌƃɾɾ ƨʍıq pʍɹı ʞʎ ɹɯʇןƨbʎ ʎɯʇb ɔbqƃןɐ Mɐqɐʍʎɯ Иbƃןɹq ɯɔ ˥ƃǝqbƃʍ

Hint:

> The first word is a song, the second already mentioned. From there, follow the instructions, and you'll arrive at the answer.

Hint 2:

> Starboard and port are ship references, what do they represent? You'll probably find out what song it is if you can figure that out.

Comment: Is it related to this? https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29942/what-would-be-required-to-prosecute-a-person-attempting-internet-fraud-in-nigeri/

Comment: @Joe-YouKnow Any hint if possible?

Comment: I'll add one now.

Comment: @ManojKumar, not directly. I needed a premise for my puzzles and I've received this type of spam before

Comment: @Joe-You-Know.. listen to him Joe.. did you book the hotel too?

Comment: Is that love? Because my friend Pat told me that it might be.

Comment: @IanMacDonald No, it is not love.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't guess the song name, but following is how I found the message:

> Translate the text upside down, you get:
> **wgqbegL cm brlgqN mywabaW algbqc qtmy yqsltmr yk irwd biws jjgv bv qbfsbems bumqe abqrwp mdempmltpm bfs sw bk sbbk spgqtms w bqw tmy swfs kgwjr bjdgppmυ pw lmmp pw wgqbegl ms sfegjc w immd bpwbjυbυmf yjlm yk bqw tmy wbjυ yk abqmleg buwf ms stm abfrwbq buwf g pqbfsm jjw bυmf jjw spmj yjqwbl buwf bjυmbυ yk elgiws kmqc kgf slbubqυ ms abgqs yjbswqbυpba g swfs yblmk bfs abzgbp pwf bf elgi slbqqtr bfs bjrlt yk elglmqfsba lg brlwspgppw qtmy abbl g bjewb ajme bfs cm pqbvmυ ms qgbf wgqbegl cm brlgqυ mywabaw kw g lgwew tmy elgsrwslmr sw sυkbssw jwlgc yk bd jjgv pgfs vlmi mty mbh qwba**

If you observe the capital letters appear at the end of words.

> So you will also need to reverse the string,
> **abwq hbm ytm imlv sfgp vgjj db ky cglwj wssbkυs ws rmlswrsgle ymt wewgl g wk wabawym υqglrb mc lgebqgw fbgq sm υmvbqp mc sfb emja bwejb g lbba ymtq wppgpswlrb gl absfqmlgle ky tlrjb sfb rtqqbls igle fb fwp pbgzba sfb kmlby sfws g abpυbqwsbjy sqgba sm υqbubls fgk cqmk swigle ky υbmυjb fwub lbwqjy jmps wjj fmυb wjj msfbqp g fwub qbwrfba mts sm fwub gelmqba ky υjbw ymt wqb ky mljy fmυbυjbwpb dmmi w cjgefs sm lgebqgw wp pmml wp υmppgdjb rjwgk sfws ymt wqb w smtqgps kbbs kb ws sfb mptlmpmedm pwrqba eqmub smebsfbq vb vgjj swib dwri ky rmtlsqy ymtq cqbgla Wabawym Nqglrb mc Lgebqgw**

Keyword:

> use BAD as caeser cipher keyword with shift of 24, you get
> **dcys jco avo konx uhir xill ec ma finyl yuucmυu yu tonuytuing aov ygyin i ym ydcdyao υsintc of nigcsiy hcis uo υoxcsr of uhc gold cyglc i nccd aovs yrriruyntc in dcuhsoning ma vntlc uhc tvsscnu king hc hyr rcibcd uhc monca uhyu i dcrυcsyucla usicd uo υscwcnu him fsom uyking ma υcoυlc hywc ncysla loru yll hoυc yll ouhcsr i hywc scythcd ovu uo hywc ignoscd ma υlcy aov ysc ma onla hoυcυlcyrc eook y flighu uo nigcsiy yr roon yr υorrielc tlyim uhyu aov ysc y uovsiru mccu mc yu uhc orvnorogeo rytscd gsowc uogcuhcs xc xill uykc eytk ma tovnusa aovs fscind Ydcdyao Psintc of Nigcsiy**

If you observe there are few words clearly visible which can be decoded using simple [substitution cipher](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/cryptogram.php#)

> But for substitution you might need to know few words from plain text to start replacement. As it is mentioned **Konami code(cheat code):- Mirrors edge**, this might mean that **Adedayo** or **Prince of Nigeria** is meant to be at the end of the text, letter count of the last words also confirms this. So you can start replacing letters at the end to form the signature.

So Final message is:

> ***Dear Joe***,
> you know this will be my final attempt at contacting you. Again I am Adedayo, prince of nigeria, heir to powers of the gold eagle. I need your assistance in dethroning my uncle the current king. He has seized the money that i desperately tried to prevent him from taking. My people have nearly lost all hope. All others i have reached out to have ignored my plea, you are my only hope. please book a flight to nigeria as soon ar possible. claim that you are a tourist. meet me at the Osun-Osogbo Sacred Grove .Together we will take back my country.
> Your freind,
> **Adedayo,
> Prince of Nigeria**.

Comment: Also this is my first post at puzzling, so please don't be stingy. :P

Comment: Excellent job. Since you got everything else, I'll let you know the last one too. The other keyword was rot13(Jne) from the song, rot13(Guvf vf Jne) from Thirty Seconds to Mars

Comment: @Joe-You-Know.. That was very tough to get.. I had tried lot of words including synomyms of rot13(Jne)..